# Match a username after a keyword

Tags: regex

I am trying to match for a username in the format of DOMAIN\USERNAME after the first appearance of a keyword "Details:"
The following is a good sample for the text that I will be looking through.

> Source: Product   |    Action: ADDUSER   |
>   Administrator: domain\admin   |    Details: Alpha Snack Foods:
>   Added user domain\fuser to the group Viewers   |

In this example I would want to return only "domain\fuser"

I have tried using `(\bdomain\\.)\w+` but this returns both "domain\admin" and "niners\fuser"

I also tried using `(?<=\buser\s)(\w+)`but this only returned the second instance of domain.

So i feel like i am getting closeish here but I could use some help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change your second attempt to allow the backslash character.

```
(?<=\buser\s)[\w\\]+
```

Or you can use `\S` which matches any non-whitespace characters.

```
(?<=\buser\s)\S+
```

Comment: This one is prettier than mine. :-)

Comment: This did the trick for the use case i have. Thanks for the explanation of the \S, makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -lne '/Added user (domain\\fuser) to the group/ and print $1' file
```

or

```
$ perl -lne '/Added user (\Qdomain\fuser\E) to the group/ and print $1' file
```

Output :

```
domain\fuser
```

Comment: Never had a look into perl yet, but seems pretty simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Details:.+(domain\\[\w]+)`

This finds "Details:" in the text, looks for all characters until domain\, then grabs the user name with domain.